# middleman Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

I want to edit a webpage for someone who is using middleman.  Anytime I run middleman in the console I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    68: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
    67: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
    66: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/middleman:23:in `<main>'
    65: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/bin/middleman:23:in `load'
    64: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.3.3/bin/middleman:49:in `<top (required)>'
    63: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-cli-4.3.3/bin/middleman:49:in `new'
    62: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/application.rb:283:in `initialize'
    61: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:28:in `block in install_methods!'
    60: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    59: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    58: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    57: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:57:in `execute'
    56: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:431:in `each'
    55: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:1316:in `traverse_depth_first'
    54: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:1316:in `each'
    53: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:57:in `block in execute'
    52: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:57:in `instance_exec'
    51: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    50: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    49: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    48: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/file_watcher.rb:47:in `before_configuration'
    47: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    46: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    45: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    44: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:241:in `poll_once!'
    43: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:241:in `reduce'
    42: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:241:in `each'
    41: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:241:in `block in poll_once!'
    40: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    39: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    38: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    37: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources/source_watcher.rb:212:in `poll_once!'
    36: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    35: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    34: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    33: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources/source_watcher.rb:288:in `update'
    32: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:28:in `block in install_methods!'
    31: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    30: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    29: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    28: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:57:in `execute'
    27: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:431:in `each'
    26: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:1316:in `traverse_depth_first'
    25: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:1316:in `each'
    24: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:57:in `block in execute'
    23: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/callback_manager.rb:57:in `instance_exec'
    22: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    21: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    20: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    19: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:351:in `did_change'
    18: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
    17: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
    16: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
    15: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:361:in `run_callbacks'
    14: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:431:in `each'
    13: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:1316:in `traverse_depth_first'
    12: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/hamster-3.0.0/lib/hamster/vector.rb:1316:in `each'
    11: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/sources.rb:368:in `block in run_callbacks'
    10: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
     9: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
     8: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
     7: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb:89:in `update_files'
     6: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb:89:in `each'
     5: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_handler.rb:138:in `block in redefine_method'
     4: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/call_with.rb:76:in `call_with'
     3: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/contracts-0.13.0/lib/contracts/method_reference.rb:43:in `send_to'
     2: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/data.rb:108:in `touch_file'
     1: from /Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/util/data.rb:60:in `parse'
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/middleman-core-4.3.3/lib/middleman-core/util/data.rb:60:in `match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

Is there a way to find out what is causing this error?  I didn't build this website, I just cloned the repository but I don't know where to start.

I've looked this up earlier and found people with a similar problem that said that it had something to do with the font files.  Even when I removed those I still have this error. If anyone could help me out I would appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks that you have an issue with an invalid byte sequence in UTF-8, see the last part of the message:   `middleman-core/util/data.rb:60:in match': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 `

Comment: This could be binary data being shunted through something that expects it to be valid UTF-8 text, which it isn't. You'll need to track down why this happens as the error here could be caused by any number of things.